# WordPress sidebar widget menu with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

For the navbar (horizontal) menu, I am using the [wp-bootstrap-navwalker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker) to display it with bootstrap 4 attributes.

However, I cannot get the default sidebar widget `menu` (vertical) of WordPress to use the bootstrap classes fully as it appears in the navbar.

My current solution is as follows where I use JQuery to replace the classes for all the `ul` and `li` elements. But as the menu widget has dropdowns and sub menus, I am not sure how to proceed with the JQuery.

How do I get the Wordpress widget menu to stack vertically, with the dropdown?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.widget ul').addClass('list-group');
    $('.widget ul > li').addClass('list-group-item');
});
```

Comment: your jquery looks fine, where do you add this code? Can you check your menu items in the debugger and see current classes an the console for any errors ?

Comment: I use this code in my default js file for the theme I am developing.

And I should clarify. The jquery works fine and the menu is actually getting displayed with bootstrap styles for the `ul` and `li` element. But the submenu is also visible, and there are no dropdown toggles like in the horizontal nav bar. I tried adding the classes using the inspector tool, and still, I couldn't get the dropdown to work in the menu widget.

Comment: can you put a link to the page ?

Comment: I'm developing it locally. The current sidebar menu looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/gC3peaU.png). The list group `ul` and `li` styles are applied, because of the jQuery code. Now, my issue is how to add proper menu classes so that it the dropdown toggle appears and the whole thing behaves like a menu.